# Ruby on Rails Syntax Error after generating project

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

I generated the project with the command `rails new reservation_maker -d mysql` and after it was finished generating I got 4 errors. All were `syntax error, unexpected ':'`. The first was in the gemfile on the line `gem 'sdoc', require: false`. The second in application_controller.rb on the line `protect_from_forgery with: :exception`. The third was in session_store.rb on the line `ReservationMaker::Application.config.session_store :cookie_store, key: '_reservation_maker_session'`. The last in wrap_parameters.rb on the line   `wrap_parameters format: [:json] if respond_to?(:wrap_parameters)`. So, what did I do wrong?

Edit:
I also looked back at a previous rails project and it has the same setup and lines of code as this one but none of the errors. Also I'm using ruby 2.0.0p353 (2013-11-22 revision 43784) [x86_64-linux] and rails 4.0.2

I just replaced the `:` with `=>` and it cleared the errors but when I try to run the server  it tells me that there is an error in the gem file

Answer (score 1):

What does `ruby -v` return?

It looks like it's crashing on hashes declared like `key: value`.  This is a new hash syntax support in ruby 1.9+.  You are probably running ruby 1.8.7 which only support hashes declared with arrows like `:key => value`.

You should install ruby 2.0 to work with new rails 4 projects.

Comment: I have `ruby 2.0.0p353 (2013-11-22 revision 43784) [x86_64-linux]` installed.

Comment: run `ruby -v` to be sure

Comment: @DGM the above info is the result from ruby -v copied and pasted

Comment: Yes, it's looks like a problem with the version of ruby. Is that the only ruby you have installed on your computer? Maybe you installed ruby 2.0, but the OS comes with ruby 1.8.7 preinstalled

Comment: @wacko. It did come with some version of ruby preinstalled, but I thought that I had removed that and installed 2.0. When I run `rvm list` and `rvm list rubies` it only shows 2.0

Answer (score 0):

Earlier when I replaced the `:` with a `=>` I didn't fully understand the difference between the two. After learning the the colon can only be used with symbols I moved the colon to the front and added the `=>` to each of the lines of the code throwing an error.

```
gem 'sdoc', require: false
protect_from_forgery with: :exception
ReservationMaker::Application.config.session_store :cookie_store, key: '_reservation_maker_session'
wrap_parameters format: [:json] if respond_to?(:wrap_parameters)
```

became

```
gem 'sdoc', :require => false
protect_from_forgery :with => :exception
ReservationMaker::Application.config.session_store :cookie_store, :key => '_reservation_maker_session'
wrap_parameters :format => [:json] if respond_to?(:wrap_parameters)
```

After that it worked. If anyone knows how to fix the behavior in rails could you please tell me.